# ggplot is squishing the x axis to one side

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an odd problem. `ggplot2` is squishing my x-axis in a really strange way. Here's the data that I'm working with:

```
   thecounter   variable value
        (dbl)     (fctr) (int)
1          -2 classrooms     4
2          -1 classrooms     3
3           0 classrooms     3
4           1 classrooms     5
5           2 classrooms    39
6          -2    offices     4
7          -1    offices     2
8           0    offices     1
9           1    offices     4
10          2    offices    43
11         -2        ALL     5
12         -1        ALL     2
13          0        ALL     4
14          1        ALL     6
15          2        ALL    37
```

When I run the following code, I get the graph that I want.

```
ggplot(tbl_df(closedtable_long),
       aes(thecounter, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]
However, when I try to relabel the x-axis marks, it only uses about 1/2 the axis, leaving the right half blank:

```
ggplot(tbl_df(closedtable_long),
        aes(thecounter, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(-2:2),
                   labels = c("Strongly Oppose", "Oppose", "Neutral",
                       "Support", "Strongly Support"))
```

[image]

I've also tried adding `limits = -2:2` to the `scale_x_discrete` bit, with no change. Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

**Data**

```
closedtable_long <- structure(list(thecounter = c(-2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, -2L, -1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L), variable = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ALL", 
"classrooms", "offices"), class = "factor"), value = c(4L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 39L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 43L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 37L)), .Names = c("thecounter", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Comment: scale_x_continuous perhaps

Comment: @user20650 -Thanks! That worked, but I don't understand why at all. Any idea?

Comment: Because your x-axis variable is continuous, not discrete. Alternatively you could of used `ggplot(dat, aes(factor(thecounter), value, fill = variable)) + ... your code as before` which seems a bit more in line with what you are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by @user20650 is:

```
ggplot(tbl_df(closedtable_long), aes(factor(thecounter), value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(-2:2), 
                   labels = c("Strongly Oppose", "Oppose",
                              "Neutral","Support", "Strongly Support"))
```

[image]